# Jenkins multipe post sections per stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two question for usage of post section in Jenkins pipeline

1.Can we use multiple post section per stage in Jenkins declarative Pipeline?

2.Can we run sh command in post section?

```
pipeline{
    stages{
        stage("....") {
            steps { 
               script {
                ....
            }
        }
        post {
          failure{
               sh "....."
            }
        }
        stage("Second stage") {
            when {
                expression { /*condition */ }
            }
            steps {
                script{

                ....
            }
            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        sh "..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find information in https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        success { 
            sh label: 'success', script: 'ls'
        }
        failure { 
            sh label: 'failure', script: 'ls'
        }
        aborted { 
            sh label: 'aborted', script: 'ls'
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `Post` steps each `Stage`, but pipeline will stop on first failure. In example below, if `Stage 1` fail `Stage 2` will be skipped. `Post` after all stages will always executed.

```
pipeline{
    stages{
        stage("Stage 1") {
            steps {
                catchError(message: 'catch failure') { 
                    script {
                        sh "echo stage 1"
                    }
                }
            }
            post {
              always {
                    sh "echo post stage 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Stage 2") {
            when {
                expression { /*condition */ }
            }
            steps {
                script{
                    sh "echo stage 2"
                }
            }
            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        sh "echo post stage 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            sh "echo post after all stages"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not find any informatin for multiple post therefore I jsut wonder that if there is any chance or not

Comment: Yes, in my answer I provide example with multi post section with sh commands

Comment: Yes but my question is use multiple post per stages..Can you check the script that I added in question

Comment: Yes, you use post per stage, see updated answer with explaining

Comment: thanks for your response that will be very useful.. Is there any way to avoid which will not skip the stage 2 if previous post is failure?

Comment: Yes, you can use `catchError` for that, check the answer update

Comment: so catchError block will run only if fails am I right? And if it fails it will still run the next stage, correct?

Comment: Code in catchError block will run always. Yes, will run next stages

Comment: Ok. So I will put the script in catchError which I would like to run always but can I se post failure after this. What I try is, if stage 1 fails then run sh command in post failure section and after run this command then continue with stage 2. If everything works well exlcude post failure and continue with stage 2 after catcherror block run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206716/discussion-between-sers-and-semural).

Comment: I would say that the official documentation doesn't present a clear example how post can be added for each stage. so thank you very much for this working example!